# Restricting memory using Process::setrlimit doesn't work

Tags: ruby, setrlimit

I want to restrict memory usage in my test, so I tested the behavior of `Process::setrlimit` first, and it confuses me. Here is my code:

```
require 'securerandom'

Process.setrlimit(:AS, 2 << 20)   # 2MB total memory, on Mac OS X
Process.setrlimit(:RSS, 2 << 20)  # 2MB resident memory, on both Mac and Linux

s = SecureRandom.hex(5 << 20)  # hexadecimal string from 5MB random data
puts s.length
```

I don't have any swap partition in my Linux laptop, so I suppose the RSS is equal to the total memory.

I expect this program to crash, but it doesn't. It just prints out `10485760` which is the correct length of that string. Why doesn't it crash? How can I correctly set the memory limit in the program itself?

Comment: Seems to work as expected for me (Arch Linux): http://pastebin.com/DWRMpQJV ... What does `Process.setrlimit` output?